# Can I add multiple events to a calendar?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'd like to add multiple events to a calendar. Today I'm looping through a long list of Event objects adding one item at a time to the calendar.  Would be nice if there was a way to add the entire list in one request?

```
foreach(var newEvent in myEventList)
{
     await graphClient.Me.Calendars[id].Events
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(newEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch to do this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching.

Using direct REST you can use

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/me/drive/root:/{file}:/content"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/me/planner/tasks"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/groups/{id}/events"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "url": "/me",
      "method": "PATCH",
      "body": {
        "city" : "Redmond"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The SDK also supports this too now very easily using BatchRequestContent and AddBatchRequestStep capability.

I demonstrated this at Ignite in Nov at the 28 min mark.
https://myignite.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/82963?source=sessions